# Solidity, hardhat failing to compile multiple Solidity versions

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm having this issue, even adding the versions in the hardhat.config file.

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
      compilers: [{version: "0.6.6"}, {version: "0.4.19"}, {version: "0.6.12"}, {version: "0.8.8"}, {version: "0.7.0"}]
  },
```

Here is still the error, What can I do?? The contract works perfectly in remix.

```
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/MarketOrder.sol (^0.8.8) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.7.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MarketOrder.sol` contract has been configured for `Solidity 0.8`, whereas the imported OpenZeppelin contract is `Solidity 0.7`

Update your [@openzeppelin/contracts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/contracts) package to the latest version or at least one that supports `^0.8.0`